# Compile/Evaluate operands in tailposition

Tags: scheme, evaluation, tail-recursion

I have a project for school for which I'm supposed to optimize a compiler/evaluator for Scheme.
The task is to implement tail-call optimization wherever possible.

I'm aware of the known tail-call optimization as shown below:

```
(define (f x)
    <send some rockets into space>
    (f (+ x 1)))
```

However, I'm thinking about evaluating operands in tail position as well. Suppose the following:

```
; The function
(define (f a b c)
    <send some monkeys into space>
    1)

; Call the function with (f 3 4 5)
(f (+ 1 2) (begin (define x 4) x) 5))
```

Evaluating the operands `(+ 1 2)`, `(begin (define x 4))` and `5` could be done in tail position, right?
Each of the operands are evaluated in their own environment. I tried this by using the regular R5RS in DrRacket with the following expression:

```
(+ (begin (define x 5) x) x)
```

If the operands would be evaluated in the same environment I would be able to pass the `x` defined in the first operand as the second operand. This is however not possible.

So, is it correct for me to assume that each operand can be evaluated in tail position?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out.

In regular R6RS operands can never be evaluated in tail position because R6RS specifies that there is no strict order in which they are evaluated.

However, in this self-built evaluator for Scheme I do specify the order in which they are evaluated. Ergo, I can strictly define which operator is the last one, and that one can be evaluated in tail position.

Comment: How exactly would you evaluate the last function-call argument as a tail call? Remember that after evaluating it, you still need to pass its value to the function call itself. A good way to think about this is, how would you implement the whole thing in CPS (continuation-passing style)? If and only if you can pass your continuation directly (with no changes) as a function call's continuation, then that is a tail call.

Comment: The built evaluator is indeed a CPS-style evaluator. If your functioncall is in tailposition, you know you will create a new environment for your body evaluation. So, the last environment in which your last operand is evaluated does not have to be restored.

Answer (score 4):

"Tail position" is always relative to some outer expression. For example, consider this:

```
(define (norm . args)
  (define (sum-of-squares sum args)
    (if (null? args)
        sum
        (let ((arg (car args)))
          (sum-of-squares (+ sum (* arg arg)) (cdr args)))))
  (sqrt (sum-of-squares 0 args)))
```

The recursive call to `sum-of-squares` is indeed in tail position relative to `sum-of-squares`. But is it in tail position relative to `norm`? No, because the return value from `sum-of-squares` is sent to `sqrt`, not directly to `norm`'s caller.

The key to analysing whether an expression A is in tail position relative to outer expression B, is to see whether A's return value is directly returned by B, without any further processing.

In your case, with your expression `(f (+ 1 2) (begin (define x 4) x) 5)` (which isn't actually valid, by the way: perhaps you meant `(f (+ 1 2) (let () (define x 4) x) 5)` instead), none of the subexpressions `(+ 1 2)`, `(let () (define x 4) x)`, and 5 are in tail position with respect to `f`, since their values have to be collected first, and *then* passed to `f` (which *is* a tail call).

Answer (score 2):

None of the operands of an application (op1 op2 ...) is in tail position.
For R5RS Scheme you can see the position in which an application occurs in a tail context here:

https://groups.csail.mit.edu/mac/ftpdir/scheme-reports/r5rs-html.old/r5rs_22.html